# How to transition overlay menu on clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I transition/animate my `.overlay` div with as little Jquery as possible? Here is an example on [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/YWXXxg). Please feel free to rewrite the JS in Codepen. Thanks very much!

**HTML**

```
          <nav>
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
              <span class="hamburger-box">
                <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
              </span>
            </button>

            <div class="overlay">
                 menu list goes hee 
             </div>
          </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: grey;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 99;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: so when button clicked, u want a transition to display the div right?

Comment: Yeah i'd like to transition the .overlay div. Basically toggle the .overlay on and off when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS version, which has a transition on height and padding-top.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.overlayclose {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

label[for="butt1"] {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
#butt1 {
  display: none;
}
#butt1:checked ~ .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: height 0.5s, padding-top 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="butt1">
  <label for="butt1">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner">Button</span>
      </span>
  </label>

  <div class="overlay">
    <label class="overlayclose" for="butt1">Close</label>
    menu list goes hee 
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is a version with script, using existing markup

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('overlayshow');
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.overlayshow {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: height 0.5s, padding-top 0.5s;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay">
    menu list goes hee 
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is a 2:nd version with script, animate top/bottom

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('overlayshow');
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  transition: top 0.5s, bottom 0.5s;
}
.overlayshow {
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s, bottom 0.5s;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay">
    menu list goes hee 
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is a 3:rd version with script, animate opacity

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('overlayshow');
})
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlayshow {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner">button</span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay">
    menu list goes hee 
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thats really cool! But i'm not in the current position to edit my html to that extent

Comment: @samsos Thanks, updated with a script sample using existing markup

Comment: this is awesome! I can simply just replace padding-top for opacity as I just want it to fade in and out?  @LGSon

Comment: @samsos Yes, by adding a child div to the overlay, the overlay itself could be transparent ... also added a 2:nd script for you, with another type of animation that might give you such effect.

Comment: Heres what i've achieved so far - http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/YWXXxg. It only fades in but not out :(

Comment: @samsos Added a 3:rd script version, animate opacity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113811/discussion-between-samsos-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transition by using `toggle` function in jquery

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $(".overlay").toggle("slow");
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w86u99L/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: because you didnt add the jquery script. Updated https://jsfiddle.net/5w86u99L/1/

Comment: Apologies I will add that in now. What you;ve provided in cool though how would I be able to close the overlay menu? That toggle would be for nothing :(

Comment: "close it" means ?